# Why is nlogn so hard to invert?

Tags: r, complexity-theory

Let's say I have a function that is nlogn in space requirements, I want to work out the maximum size of input for that function for a given available space.  i.e. I want to find n where nlogn=c.

I followed [an approach](http://cs-people.bu.edu/lapets/resource/nlogn.pdf) to calculate n, that looks like this in R:

```
step = function(R, z) { log(log(R)-z)} 
guess = function(R) log(log(R))

inverse_nlogn = function(R, accuracy=1e-10) {
 zi_1 = 0
 z = guess(R)
 while(abs(z - zi_1)>accuracy) { 
  zi_1 = z
  z = step(R, z)
 }
 exp(exp(z))
}
```

But I can't get understand *why* it must be solved iteratively.  For the range we are interested (n>1), the function is non singular.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing special about *n* log *n* — nearly all elementary functions fail to have elementary inverses, and so have to be solved by some other means: bisection, Newton's method, Lagrange inversion theorem, series reversion, Lambert W function...

Comment: You can download it in full [from the AMS](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As Gareth hinted the Lambert W function ([eg here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)) gets you almost there, indeed n = c/W(c)

A wee google found [this](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/03b/7038.html), which might be helpful.

Comment: you can source() it from there, or install the emdbook package ... I think there's also a version in the GSL package

Answer (score 2):

Following up (being completely explicit):

```
library(emdbook)

n <- 2.5

c <- 2.5*log(2.5)
exp(lambertW(c))  ## 2.5

library(gsl)
exp(lambert_W0(c)) ## 2.5
```

There are probably minor differences in speed, accuracy, etc. of the two implementations.  I haven't tested/benchmarked them extensively.  (Now that I tried

```
library(sos)
findFn("lambert W")
```

I discover that it's implemented all over the place: the games package, and a whole package that's called LambertW ...