# Compute size N that can be solved in certain amount of time

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am working on an exercise (note no homework question) where a number of steps that can be exercised by a computer are given and one is asked to compute N in relation to certain time intervals for multiple functions some functions.

I have no problem doing this for functions such as `f(n) = n, n^2, n^3` and the like.

But when it comes to `f(n) = lgn, sqrt(n), n log n, 2^n, and n!` i run into problems.

It is clear to me that I that I have to construct a term of the form `func(n) = interval` and then have to get n.

But how to do this with the functions above?

Can somebody please give me an example, or name the inverse functions so that I can look it up on wikipedia or somewhere else.

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking about. Can you explain better or provide an example?

Comment: How can this be: function (n) = interval ? How is value of your function an interval ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't so much about algorithms, or complexity, but about inversions of math formulas.

It's easy to solve for *n* in *n^k = N* in a closed form. Unfortunately, for most other functions it is either not known or known that it is not possible. In particular, for *n log(n)*, the solution [involves the Lambert function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400175/why-is-nlogn-so-hard-to-invert), which doesn't help you much.

In most cases, you will have to solve this kind of stuff numerically.